# Nested forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, heroku

Been googling around but I can't find any help on this. I am trying to dynamically add fields to a nested form I have been creating. The current code is:

**Controller**

```
if @jobstream.complex_attributes == []      
        @functional_group.functional_type_stores.each do |ftype|
                if(Type.find(ftype.type_id).simple_or_complex == 'C' || Type.find(ftype.type_id).simple_or_complex == 'c' )
                    @jobstream.complex_attributes.build(:type_id => Type.find(ftype.type_id).id)
                end
        end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= f.fields_for :complex_attributes do |f_sa| %>
    <tr>
        <div class="field">
            <td><%= @complexType[@counter].display_name %></td>
            <td><%= @complexType[@counter].simple_or_complex %></td>
            <%= f_sa.hidden_field :type_id%>
            <td><%= f_sa.text_field :content, :size => 100 %></td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <% (@counter += 1) %>
<% end %>
```

What I need is a method of being able to dynamically add another text field to the complex attribute while creating a unique id for the complex attribute and also retaining the `hidden_field type_id` value of the complex attribute you wish to add more fields to.

For a quick reference to hopefully explain this better go [here](http://warm-snow-7155.heroku.com/functional_groups) and hit create jobstream - I basically want to be able to have a list of complex attributes with a button next to them allowing you to add more text fields for that same attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't add more attribute pairs to an existing model(more than fields in db), you might have to create another model that is owned by @jobstream model. This new model will then store attributes, and will have to be called with the @jobstream model.

In the form, you'll have to add the fields remotely, and to avoid errors, you'll need to use Model.create, instead of Model.new(as the nested form will crash otherwise). Also, you'll need new fields_for tag for each added field.

That would be for the Rails way, I guess.

You can also try to store these new attributes as hash in designated field - for example, you can have fields like

```
<%= fields_for :complex_attributes, do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :attr_foo %>
<%= f.text_field :attr_new %>
<%= f.text_field :another_attr_new %>...
```

And then after updating form you can retrieve these attributes by using `Model.complex_attributes.each_pair do |key, value|`
The problem here is with adding more fields, you might need to hardcode these fields, and also, it is a must to assign new key for each new field.

It can be done, though. I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked these:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

by chance?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the methods there aren't suited to my needs (I believe with them I could add brand new attributes rather than extensions of current ones).